# Passing value to the Django view function from template

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

```
{% for key,value in ls.items %}

    {% if value == "1" %}

        <form id="myForm" action="/data_display/" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="date_selected" value= {{ key }}>
            <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('myForm').submit();"><font size="+1">{{ key }}</font>><br>available</a>
            {% csrf_token %}
        </form>
    {% else %}

        <p>
         <font> {{key}} </font></br>
         not available
        </p>


    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Here, "ls" is the dictionary. I want to pass the "key" to Django views function. The value in the input tag does take different values of key during each for loop, but when I pass when I click on the link, it only passes the key of 1st element.

For eg, suppose my dictionary is:

```
{'2020_01_01': '1', '2020_01_02': '1', '2020_01_03': '0', '2020_01_04': '1', '2020_01_05': '0', '2020_01_06': '0', '2020_01_07': '0', '2020_01_08': '1', '2020_01_09': '0'}
```

so when I click on any of the link, "2020_01_01,2020_01_02,2020_01_04,2020_01_08", every time only 2020_01_01 key passes to the view function. But I want that whenever I click on any other link like 2020_01_02, then 2020_01_02 should pass on the view function.

Answer (score 0):

If you take int in dict values then you don't need to compare explicitly and use more pythonic way, just try this:

```
{% for key,value in ls.items %}

{% if value %}

    <form id="myForm" action="/data_display/" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="date_selected" value= {{ key }}>
        <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('myForm').submit();">{{ key }} available</a>
        {% csrf_token %}
    </form>
{% else %}

    <p>
     <font> {{key}} </font></br>
     not available
    </p>


{% endif %}
```

{% endfor %}

I hope this works!

Comment: It didn't work. I want to pass the "key" to another view function called "data_display".

Answer (score 0):

[image]View.py

```
def index(request):
      ls= {'2020_01_01': '1', '2020_01_02': '1', '2020_01_03': '0', '2020_01_04': '1', '2020_01_05': '0', '2020_01_06': '0', '2020_01_07': '0', '2020_01_08': '1', '2020_01_09': '0'}
      return render(request, 'index.html',context={'ls':ls})
```

Template(index.html)
Put your code:

```
{% for key,value in ls.items %}

{% if value == "1" %}

    <form id="myForm" action="/data_display" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" id="date_selected" name="date_selected" value= "{{ key }}">
         <button class="btn btn-default submit" type="submit">Send</button>

    </form>
{% else %}

    <p>
     <font> {{key}} </font></br>
     not available
    </p>


{% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

@Meha Parekh it will return all results, because value isnt None

Comment: From this index.html, I want to pass the "key" to another view function called "data_display". I already have a function in the view similar to your index function from where I have called index.html.

Comment: You need to have another function:

def data_display(request):

    date_selected= request.POST['date_selected']

Please try to update your code on project with the code that I suggested...

Comment: Yes, I do have that function in my views. And I want to pass the "key" from template to this function.

Comment: Can you share your function data_display?

Comment: def data_display(request):
    
    date_selected = request.POST['date_selected']
    print(date_selected)
    obj = ret_tbl.objects.filter(curr_date = date_selected)
    context = {
        'date_selected' : date_selected,
        'obj' : obj
    }
    return render(request, 'retention/data.html', context)

Comment: Here, date_selected always gets "2020_01_01".

Comment: url(r'^data_display', views.data_display,name="data_display") Add this to your urlpatterns and update the template with submit button. Date selected will get dynamic values, I add an image

Comment: I have included the path in my urls. See, the code which I have shown in the question will display the boxes on chrome page which will contain the dates which are clickable. So when I click to any particular date, I should redirect to another chrome page showing me the data of that particular date. But when I click any date other than 2020_01_01, "data_display" is always getting 2020_01_01. And i want is that that when I click 2020_01_02 date, then data_display sholud get 2020_01_02